# How can a class notify somebody that its data have been altered?

Tags: c#, winforms

Lets say there is a `Person` class that holds some attributes and some other classes `Address` etc. (I am just giving an example of class{class{data}})

An instance of this is deserialized and loaded in the ui. The used might change the data (the name, the address or something).

If the instance is the datasource in the ui(in every control), how can I know if the data has been changed in order to notify the user to Save before exit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface, which basically exposes an event that `Person` should raise when a property changes.

The linked documentation gives an example with a `DemoCustomer` class which is likely to translate pretty easily into your `Person` class.

Comment: @SLaks provided me this link to automatically tie in the notifiers at compile time. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bd351303-db8c-4771-9b22-5e51524fccd3

Comment: This way, I'll have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in every class and each parent class should catch the event from its children and raise another INotifyPropertyChanged.
This is the first thing I tried but will make the code annoying.

Comment: @Odys: Well that's basically what there is... with suitable helpers, it's not *terribly* hard, and you can use AOP if you want, at the cost of an extra concept to understand. It's the price you pay for needing change notification.

Comment: Having an answer by "you" is like ensuring that I am not missing another way of doing it. thanks anyway

Comment: @Odys: Oh don't put any faith in my omniscience. It's vastly over-reported ;) Personally I'm not a *huge* fan of AOP as it can make it harder to understand what's really going on sometimes - but it can certainly reduce boilerplate code.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid anoying code for every property of every class you did and will do, you can use one of [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)  frameworks. This one is one of the best actually available on market now: [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). And there is also a free version, which is a good news. (by the way keep an eye on licensing, in case you're gonna use it at your work)

Here you can actually find an example how to use precisely for injecting of NotifyPropertyChanged

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions#ui

Hope this helps..